# Load only visible images in Flatlist react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have made a grid of images using Flatlist. I am loading the images from the web. Currently, all the images are loaded as soon as I navigate to that particular page. What I want is only load those images which are visible on the screen and rest on the scroll. Six images are shown at one time on the screen.

Is it possible to load images on the scroll in Flatlist?

Answer (score 7):

The properties you need to combine are actually [initialNumToRender](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#initialnumtorender) and [windowSize](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist.html#windowsize). If you only want one screen of images visible at a time, you would use `windowSize={1}`. I, personally recommend you use at least windowSize={3} so you have the previous and the next screens rendered buut it really depends on the sizes of the images you are showing.
Also note that the items specified with `initialNumToRender` will never be removed. This is to allow "Go to top" functionality. You may or may not want such items.

It is also good to note that you may need to implement some kind of caching of those images. Once you "unrender" them and you need to render them again a new request would be made for them, causing more bandwidth being used on your user's device.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with the [initialNumToRender](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#initialnumtorender) property on flat list.

so your flatList declaration might be:

```
<FlatList
    initialNumToRender={2}
    data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
    renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Flatlist` as below to load only those images which are in the current viewport.

```
             <FlatList
                    ref={(view) => (this.parentScrollView = view)}
                    data={this.state.data}
                    onScroll={this.handleScroll}
                    keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    bounces={false}
                    numColumns={3}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.ItemSeparatorComponent}
                    ListEmptyComponent={this.ListEmptyComponent}

                    //code for optimization and load only visible items
                    initialNumToRender={8}
                    maxToRenderPerBatch={2}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
                    onMomentumScrollBegin={this.onMomentumScrollBegin}
                    onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
           />
```

My `onEndReached` is:

```
onEndReached = () => {
        console.log('end reached');
        if (!this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum) {
            console.log('loading more archived products');
            this.loadMoreProducts();                
            this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = true;
        }
    }
```

And `onMomentumScrollBegin` is:

```
onMomentumScrollBegin = () => { this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = false; }
```

`initialNumToRender` will mount the first 8 items and will never remove them unless the `Flatlist` itself doesn't get unmounted. It is helpful to preserve list scrolling performance while fast scrolling the list.

`onMomentumScrollBegin` and `onEndReachedThreshold` is used to when to load more element for the list. This could be an API call etc.